# How to stop all running timers in java?

Tags: java, swing, timer

In my project, I collect continous data from database and pass it to dynamictimeseriescollection and generate graph using timer. here i am using 2 timers for generating 2 graphs.

```
  private Timer timer;
  timer = new Timer(100, new ActionListener() 
  {
    -----
    -----
  }
  timer.start();
```

Like this another one also simultaneously working. If i select another database to generate graph like My SQL to SQL Server means, these timers were running without stopping. So processing speed is too slow. How can i stop all running timers while selecting another option?

Comment: `timer.stop()`? I mean, for each timer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to store each `Timer` instance in either an [array](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) or an [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), and then call `timer.stop()` on each stored timer when you want to cancel them all.

Comment: In my project, every timer in different classes to generate individual jfreechart. So in main class, if i stop those timers by using,   **Graph.timer.stop(); Graph1.timer.stop();** means it wont execute the first line itself. the program just hang without any response.

Comment: As far as I can recall, AWT timers should be fine with that. Is there anything anywhere else that could be causing the freezing? Of course, it has been a while since I've used timers, so I could have forgotten something.